# address tag for seo help google?

Tags: html, tags, street-address

does address HTML tag helps for SEO, it shows map when searching??

If it does, i need that for events website, so can i set address tag `display: hidden`, and seo will work fine?

```
<address style="display:hidden">
Box 564, Disneyland
USA
</address>
```

or it needs to be displayed on website?

Should i use it on website for events?

Or i need to use some other tags for this kind of website?

Comment: Anything that is `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` (display:hidden, doesn't exist) is pretty much guaranteed not to help SEO.

Comment: @Alohci, I don’t think there’s much solid evidence about they way search engines process CSS. A reasonable expectation is that they mostly ignore it, though they might try to heuristically detect attempts at fooling them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Fair point. SEO is not my expertise. I generally go on the principle that search engines will do what's in their interest. Indexing text that the ordinary user can't see first up when they visit the page will likely make the perception of their search results worse, for the same reason that they don't index meta keywords. So I figure they'd process basic text hiding css, even if most css was ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect that search engines do anything specific with `address` elements. By the specification, such an element specifies contact information for the *author* of the page (or part of a page), but actual usage of `address` is mixed. The best search engines can do with `address` markup is to ignore the tags.

A more constructive approach is to use low-level metadata as per [Event](http://schema.org/Event) at Schema.org. However, it seems that search engines use such markup only for major commercial and community sites only, where the markup is generally generated from a database rather than handcrafted.